# how can i turn off lines from "Report Server" on my SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, sql-server-profiler

It's my first time using SQL Server Profiler and I'm wondering **how can i turn off event lines from the application "Report Server" on my SQL Server Profiler?** I just want certain activities to be logged like ones from LINQPad and Entity Framework.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you basically want to create a filter on the specified column within SQL Server Profiler.

When you go inside profiler and you are selecting your events, there is a button in the bottom right corner that is called "Column Filters...".  Click on that, and you can create a `LIKE`/`NOT LIKE` filter on `ApplicationName`, or any column you so desire to filter based on.

Comment: wow, I've been stumped on this for a long time.. thanks for this one! I'd upvote this but I only have 10 rep so far..